# Mongo DB: How to copy the Document from one collection and add it as a field to a related document from another collection?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

2 Collections are available in the DB:

**Products**:

```
{
   "_id":"unique_product_id",
   "name":"Product 1",
   "price":50
}
```

**Events**:

```
{
   "_id":"unique_event_id_1",
   "product_id":"unique_product_id",
   "action":"created"
},
{
   "_id":"unique_event_id_2",
   "product_id":"unique_product_id",
   "action":"updated"
}
```

where `Events` collection contains documents associated with documents from `Products` collection.
The idea that I have is just to inject documents from `Events` collection to `Products`, as results the `Products` will look like:

**Products**:

```
{
   "_id":"unique_product_id",
   "name":"Product 1",
   "price":50,
   "events":[
      {
         "_id":"unique_event_id",
         "product_id":"unique_product_id_1",
         "action":"created"
      },
      {
         "_id":"unique_event_id",
         "product_id":"unique_product_id_1",
         "action":"updated"
      }
   ]
}
```

And I want to understand if it possible to implement it as part of the `Mongodb Aggregation framework`?

I need to find something like `$out` that takes the documents returned by the aggregation pipeline and writes them to a specified collection, but I need to write not to a specific collection, but to the specific document of the specific collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in MongoDB 4.4, [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#pipe._S_merge) can output to the same collection that is being aggregated:

```
db.products.aggregate([       
   { /**
    * from: The target collection.
    * localField: The local join field.
    * foreignField: The target join field.
    * as: The name for the results.
    * pipeline: The pipeline to run on the joined collection.
    * let: Optional variables to use in the pipeline field stages.
    */
   $lookup: {
     from: 'events',
     localField: '_id',
     foreignField: 'product_id',
     as: 'events'
   }},
   {/**
    * into: The target collection.
    * on: Fields to  identify.
    * whenMatched: Action for matching docs.
    * whenNotMatched: Action for non-matching docs.
    */
   $merge: {
     into: 'products',
     on: "_id",
     whenMatched: 'merge',
     whenNotMatched: 'insert'
   }}
])
```

**Be aware:** when $merge outputs to the same collection that is being aggregated, documents may get updated multiple times or the operation may result in an infinite loop. More details here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#merge-behavior-same-collection

If it is a one off update you can safeguard the pipeline by adding initial filter as the first stage to ensure a document is updated exactly once:

```
{ $match: { events: { $exists: false } }
```

Comment: on: "_id" - what does it mean for my particular case? Which _id is used?

Comment: `on: "_id"` is how it is going to merge the documents back into your `products` collection, you can also specify more than one field here (as an array)

Comment: It would worth mentioning the disclaimer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#merge-behavior-same-collection The pipeline is idempotent and can handle multiple updates of the same document with easy, but a chance to catch the "infinite loop" is still here. It might not be suitable for everyone.

Comment: true, so i have added the $match stage to avoid processing the documents that have already been processed

Comment: This is a tricky one. It may be okay if OP uses it as a one off update. If the intention is to run it periodically to update products with new events this filter won't let new events to be added to the existing arrays. The answer is good enough as an example of valid usecase for this new v4.4 feature. My comment was just to raise awareness about limitations of the method for readers to make an informed decision whether it works in their particular case.