# MongoDB: How to copy Documents to a new field of associated Documents from other collections?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Collections that I have:

Product:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"product_id_1",
      "name":"Product 1",
      "price":50
   },
   {
      "_id":"product_id_2",
      "name":"Product 2",
      "price":100
   }
]
```

Category:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"category_id_1",
      "name":"Category 1"
   },
   {
      "_id":"category_id_2",
      "name":"Category 2"
   }
]
```

Audit:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"audit_id_1",
      "resource_type":"product",
      "resource_id":"product_id_1",
      "attribute":"name",
      "executionTime":"2021-01-10T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "_id":"audit_id_2",
      "resource_type":"product",
      "resource_id":"product_id_1",
      "attribute":"name",
      "executionTime":"2021-01-09T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "_id":"audit_id_3",
      "resource_type":"product",
      "resource_id":"product_id_1",
      "attribute":"price",
      "executionTime":"2021-01-10T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "_id":"audit_id_4",
      "resource_type":"category",
      "resource_id":"category_id_1",
      "attribute":"name",
      "executionTime":"2021-01-10T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "_id":"audit_id_5",
      "resource_type":"category",
      "resource_id":"category_id_1",
      "attribute":"name",
      "executionTime":"2021-01-09T00:00:00.000Z"
   }
]
```

Collection `Audit` is using for saving details about each `Product` or `Category` documents updates.
For example, we see that the attribute `name` of `Product` with `id` `product_id_1` was changed twice:
`9th of January` and `10th of January`.

attribute `price` of the same `Product` was changed only once: `10th of January`.

The same kind of information saved for `Category` collection as well.

*The goal that I want to achieve is*:
Extract existing Documents from `Audit` collection that contain information only about the latest changes for each unique `attribute` per each unique `resource` and copy them to a new field of related document of `Product`/`Category` collections.

As result, the `Product`/`Category` collections should look like this:

Product:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"product_id_1",
      "name":"Product 1",
      "price":50,
      "audit":[
         {
            "_id":"audit_id_1",
            "resource_type":"product",
            "resource_id":"product_id_1",
            "attribute":"name",
            "executionTime":"2021-01-10T00:00:00.000Z"
         },
         {
            "_id":"audit_id_3",
            "resource_type":"product",
            "resource_id":"product_id_1",
            "attribute":"price",
            "executionTime":"2021-01-10T00:00:00.000Z"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"product_id_2",
      "name":"Product 2",
      "price":100,
      "audit":[
         
      ]
   }
]
```

Category:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"category_id_1",
      "name":"Category 1",
      "audit":[
         {
            "_id":"audit_id_4",
            "resource_type":"category",
            "resource_id":"category_id_1",
            "attribute":"name",
            "executionTime":"2021-01-10T00:00:00.000Z"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"category_id_2",
      "name":"Category 2",
      "audit":[
         
      ]
   }
]
```

I tried to write a query by myself, and this is what I got:

```
db.getCollection("audit").aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
     "resource_type": "product"}
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      executionTime: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        property: "$attribute",
        entity: "$resource_id"
      },
      document: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$document"
    }
  }
]).forEach(function(a){
db.getCollection("product").update({"_id" :ObjectId(a.resource_id)},{addToSet : {audit:[a]}})
});
```

The problems that I see with my solution are:
it will update only one `Product` collection. It means that I need to execute my code at list twice, for each existing collections.
`forEach` statement, I am not sure where exactly this command executed on the server-side or on client-side, assume `Audit` collection contains approx **100k** documents, from the performance point of view, how fast this command will be executed?

So, definitely, I have a feeling that I need to rewrite my solution, but I have doubts about how to make it better.

For example, I read about `$merge` command, which can do a quite similar job that I do in `forEach` section, but I do not know how to apply `$merge` in the aggregation flow that I wrote above properly.

Comment: How this question is different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66127428/mongo-db-how-to-copy-the-document-from-one-collection-and-add-it-as-a-field-to you asked yesterday?  There was a good answer with an example of how to do both $lookup and $merge. If anything is not clear, please ask there, don't spam.

Comment: @AlexBlex more complex

Comment: Fair enough. If the simpler question was answered, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @AlexBlex, can you make any suggestions regarding the actual question? it is much appreciated.

Comment: Still reading. The complexity seems to come from the outlining of the problem. Can't get my head around what you are trying to do. The only comment I can give at the moment is the forEach is executed on the clientside.

Comment: @AlexBlex, I need to know when the price/name/or any other attribute was changed last time, I do not want to have historical information about all changes for some particular attribute.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `forEach` is executed on the client side, which means you download result of the aggregation and make 1 update request per each document in the result. Although it is the most flexible way it is the most expensive one. Aggregation pipeline with $out and $merge on the other hand is executed on the serverside so you don't pipe data through the client.

Secondly, if you need to update 2 collections you will need at least 2 queries. There is no way to $out to multiple collections.

Finally, you need to use the [subquery syntax of the $lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries). It is more flexible and let you define "joining" logic in pipeline terms. For products it would be:

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "audit",
      let: {
        id: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        { "$match": {
            $expr: { $eq: [ "$resource_id", "$$id" ] },  // the foreign key match 
            resource_type: "product"                     // the discriminator
        } },
        { $sort: { "executionTime": -1 } },              // chronological order
        { "$group": {
            _id: {
              attribute: "$attribute",                   // for each unique attribute
              id: "$resource_id"                         // per each unique resource
            },
            value: {
              $first: "$$ROOT"                           // pick the latest
            }
        } },
        { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$value" } }
      ],
      as: "audit"
    }
  }
])
```

The $out stage and its limitations you already learned from [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66127428/mongo-db-how-to-copy-the-document-from-one-collection-and-add-it-as-a-field-to).

The second pipeline to update categories will be exactly the same but with another $out destination and another value in the discriminator.

Comment: I have just posted my version of the code that does exactly the same, please take a look. I am very interested in your opinion.

Comment: Good one. I assume the `_id`s are ObjectID and there are no id clashes between products and categories. The subqueries can benefit from indexes on both collections but on 100k documents the difference will be negligible.

Comment: I have tried to execute the query on on our dev environment, where MongoDB server 4.2.12 installed and I have got the following error: "$merge is not supported when the output collection is the same as the aggregation collection".

Comment: Versions of MongoDB prior to 4.4 did not allow $merge to output to the same collection as the collection being aggregated. (((

Comment: Yeah, I updated the previous answer to make it more clear. I mentioned it in the comments but apparently it was not visible enough. I'm afraid there are not much you can do with v4.2 tbh.

Comment: I have just spoken with our devops, they told me, that they can't update MongoDB server to 4.4 just now, because other services will be affected as well, they need to investigate update to determine potential risks and side effects.  So, I am a little bit shocked, spent a lot of time and now I realize that our solution not applicable now.  What can you recommend me to do?

Comment: Push harder? Change job? Write a script to update documents clientside?  There is no easy solution and it's on you to decide what to do. There are too many factors to consider  and nobody knows your circumstances better than you do.

Comment: I was asking, about possible query implementation for the MongoDB version 4.2. Do you think only client-side handling is possible? I mean, only forEach?

Comment: Yes, there is no way to run such update serverside in v4.2. forEach is the simplest and the least reliable option but it really depends on how critical it is for business. If it is one off update you can try to $out to new collection, delete the source then rename the new to the original. It should be done within maintenance window to ensure no data loss.

Answer (score 1):

want to post the code written by myself:

```
db.getCollection("product").aggregate([
{ $match: {} },

{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'audit',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'resource_id',
        as: 'audit'
    }
},

{
    $unwind: '$audit'
},

{
    $sort: { "audit.executionTime": -1 }
},

{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            property: "$audit.attribute",
            entity: "$audit.resource_id"
        },
        document: {
            $first: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
},

{
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$document"
    }
},

{
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        audit: { $push: "$audit" }
    }
},

{
    $merge: {
        into: 'product',
        on: "_id",
        whenMatched: 'merge',
        whenNotMatched: 'insert'
    }
}])
```